# Using modules in Deployd

Tags: deployd

I have started to use Deployd. It works great. However, I need to use other node modules and I am running into problems - how am I supposed to use functionality from other node modules in my Deployd app?

For instance, I am using Paymill.com for credit card payments and Paymill provides a node module for using their API. How can I use their module in my app? I have tried to load the module (using require("name-of-the-module")) in the event scripts in the dashboard but it fails becaus require() is not defined.

What is the preferred solution?

Answer (score 0):

Deployd has its own module system:
http://docs.deployd.com/docs/developing-modules/creating-modules.md

Building a paymill module for deployd would definitively benefit the community :)

There's [some possibilities](https://gist.github.com/LordotU/4555637) to have require() work in the event script, but it's not a very clean approach.